# random.choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

When I type this:

```
rand_num = random.choice(1, 101)
```

It shows:

```
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

These are all put in functions and I don't get why it says this.

Comment: Looks like you were looking for [`random.randrange(start, stop)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature for [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) is:

```
choice(seq)
```

You pass it a sequence such as:

```
>>> random.choice([1, 2, 6, 8, 9])
2
```

A `range` object is also valid as shown in the other answer here.

You might logically ask, why does Python tell you that `choice()` *takes 2 positional arguments* rather than just one (`seq`)? That's because `choice()` implicitly [takes a `self` parameter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/91a639a094978882caef91915c932fbb2fc347de/Lib/random.py#L376) since it's an instance method. But for your intents and purposes as the function caller, you're expected to pass just one argument, which is a sequence, such as a list or tuple.

Answer (score 2):

It may seem strange that the error says 3 arguments were given when you only put in 2, but what you might not know is that the [`random.choice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) method is actually a bound method of a [`random.Random()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.Random) object.

So when the error says `but 3 were given`, they are including the `self` parameter that you didn't pass in. Here is a demonstration of a more clear scenario for the error:

```
obj = random.Random()
rand_num = random.Random.choice(obj, 1, 101)
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    random.Random.choice(obj, 1, 101)
TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

The way to fix it is simple; pass the `1` and `101` into the `range()` method to convert the two numbers into a single element:

```
rand_num = random.choice(range(1,101))
```

But the more practical method would be to use the [`random.randint()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) method:

```
rand_num = random.randint(1,100)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want to do:

```
rand_num = random.choice(range(1,101))
```

[The docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice) says that you must pass a sequence to `choice()` (in this example, a range).

Answer (score 0):

Choice makes a random choice from a given direct, such `[1,2,3,4,5....]`
Seeing what you need:

1. if you choose something random from the list then:
   `rand_num = random.choice([1,2,3,...., 101])`
2. if you need a random number from 1 to 101, such that a <= rand_num <= b - then use `randint`:
   `rand_num = random.randint(1, 101)` or you may use standard function `range(start, stop, step)` 
   `rand_num = random.choice(range(1, 101, 1))`

Answer (score 0):

The random.choice method only takes 1 parameter but you give 6 but you can try this:

```
import random

def rollDie():
    return random.choice((1,2,3,4,5,6))
    # - or -
    # return random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6])
    # - or -
    # return random.randint(1,6)
    # - or -
    # return random.randrange(1,7)

print(rollDie())
```