# choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given, but pretty sure I gave 2

Tags: python

I'm making a simulation of the Monty Hall problem, and this snippet is the swapping part.

```
import random

i = 0
eliminated = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    randFirstChoice = random.randint(1,3)
    if randFirstChoice == 1:
        eliminated += random.choice(2, 3)
    elif randFirstChoice == 2:
        eliminated += random.choice(1, 3)
    elif randFirstChoice == 3:
        eliminated += random.choice(1, 2)
    print(eliminated)
```

Whenever I run this, I get the error

> TypeError: choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

The line numbers it gives for the errors are the 3 condition statements.
I'm confused because I thought that `random.choice` would let me choose between two numbers randomly, and as far as I can tell that's what I tried to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [random.choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66316497/random-choice-takes-2-positional-arguments-but-3-were-given)

Answer (score 7):

`random.choice` is actually a bound method of a single shared `random.Random` instance. The top level functions of `random` that match `random.Random` method names are all made this way; it saves reimplementing the same functionality twice.

The two arguments are `self` (passed implicitly since it's pre-bound) and the sequence to choose from. You passed `self` (implicitly), and two non-sequence arguments (explicitly).

If you mean to choose between two values, pass them as a `tuple`, e.g.:

```
import random
i = 0
eliminated = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    randFirstChoice = random.randint(1,3)
    if randFirstChoice == 1:
        eliminated += random.choice((2, 3))  # Extra parens for a tuple
    elif randFirstChoice == 2:
        eliminated += random.choice((1, 3))  # Extra parens for a tuple
    elif randFirstChoice == 3:
        eliminated += random.choice((1, 2))  # Extra parens for a tuple
    print(eliminated)
```

Comment: @SamBam: If you want it to be one of the options chosen, why are you using `+=`? Seems like you want it to just be `eliminated = `, not `eliminated += `.

Answer (score 0):

put your `random.choice` takes a sequence in input.

```
import random
i = 0
eliminated = 0
while i < 10:
    i += 1
    randFirstChoice = random.randint(1,3)
    if randFirstChoice == 1:
        eliminated += random.choice([2, 3])
    elif randFirstChoice == 2:
        eliminated += random.choice([1, 3])
    elif randFirstChoice == 3:
        eliminated += random.choice([1, 2])
    print(eliminated)
```

`random.choice` is a class method. whose first parameter(`self`) is already set as a first parameter of function.

following is the code of `choice` function in backend(random.py).

```
    def choice(self, seq):
        """Choose a random element from a non-empty sequence."""
        try:
            i = self._randbelow(len(seq))
        except ValueError:
            raise IndexError('Cannot choose from an empty sequence') from None
        return seq[i]
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you misunderstood the use of the method.
`random.choice()` takes only one parameter which has to be a list. Try `random.choice(['a','b','c'])`. If you want a number in a range you could use `random.randint(2,30)`

Comment: I wasn't trying to have it be a number in a range I was trying to make it pick between the two nubers.

Comment: Not a problem, you can just use random.choice inserting into the list the numbers.. I hope you solved the problem